# Can't create directory in Android with apk created with with Python/Kivy and Buildozer in Colab

Tags: android, permissions, buildozer

I'm deeply sorry as I am not a professioanl programmer but I have my own simple application for Android, a-la "Hello world" that stopped working.

It used to work for half a year but when I came back to it to create new apk-file the application stopped working.

During troubleshooting process I found out that my application can't create directory in Android phone:

```
os.mkdir('/storage/emulated/0/MK_Eng')
```

The path is correct. Permissions are granted. All modules are imported. And it used to work!

I've lost several days to make it work again - unsuccessfully... Need your help! Thank you!

Here is an excerpt:

```
import os

if kivy.platform == 'win':
    dirname='C:/MK_Eng/'
    filename='C:/MK_Eng/eng-rus-new.txt'
elif kivy.platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    dir = primary_external_storage_path()
    dirname = os.path.join(dir, 'MK_Eng')
    filename='/storage/emulated/0/MK_Eng/eng-rus-new.txt'


if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
    # Create Directory
    os.mkdir(dirname)
```

I tried to adjust some buildozer settings but still no luck.

```
#(list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt

#(list) Application requirements
#comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,android.permissions

#(list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

#(str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = develop
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes on Android 11+ devices an app cannot create files and directories in root of external storage as you try to do.

Instead use one of the many public directories that are already there.

Like DCIM, Pictures, Documents, Download,...

Comment: Thank you! I do use Android 10 on my phone, but I'll do try.

Comment: That will not help as for Android 10 devices you have to add legacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file and after that you can use your old path.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry, but should this legacyExternalStorage="true" be done within Python/Kivy code or by some other means? Sorry for this stupid like question...

Comment: I do not program with Python,/Kivy sorry. But isnt there something like an AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Unfortunately, my attempt to create new directory within Download '/storage/emulated/0/Download/MK_Eng/' failed again. :(      I do try to find out how this 'legacyExternalStorage="true"' can be implemented in Python/Kivy code or through buildozer settings. I would appeciate any help from the community.

Comment: You better start a new thread asking for it.